# Pass ALL Arguments from Bash Script to Another Command

Tags: bash, scripting, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments

What is the simplest way to grab all the given arguments for a bash script and pass them all into another command within the script? For example:

Command Line:

```
./runProgram.sh [ARGS HERE]
```

Script:

```
#! /bin/bash
cd bin/
java com.myserver.Program [ARGS HERE]
```